# mirroring and controlling Ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu

I recently installed Ubuntu Touch on my Oneplus One and was wondering if it is possible to control and mirror it on my laptop.

Like [scrcpy](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=scrcpy&t=brave&ia=web) for android, is there something for ubuntu touch?